# Cauchy sequences are bounded?!

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm having trouble understanding the proof that Cauchy sequences are bounded, here's the proof I've been given

> Let $s_n$ be a Cauchy sequence. *We take a concrete value of $\varepsilon$, for simplicity $1$, then there exists a natural number $n_0$ such that $$|s_m-s_n|\leq 1\;\;\;\; \forall m,n\geq n_0$$
>   Hence (fixing $m=n_0$) we have* $$|s_n-s_{n_0}|\leq 1 \;\;\; \forall n\geq n_0$$

And the proof goes on to explain how this is used to bound $|s_n|$ for all $n\geq n_0$ and therefore for $n\leq n_0$ there are a finite number of terms so its just the max of the bounds etc. I understand that. However its the parts in the italics that I can't understand. How can you fix $\varepsilon$ and $s_m$ when they should be variables and the proof should cover $\forall \varepsilon>0$ and $\forall m\geq n_0$?

Comment: In response to the punctuation in the title: Yes!!! They are!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lemma: Cauchy sequences are bounded.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999633/lemma-cauchy-sequences-are-bounded)

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to *show* that something holds for all $\epsilon>0$ and for all $m\ge m_0$, you want to make *use* of this fact (that is given). For this you are allowed to specialize to a (valid) choice of $\epsilon$ and/or $m$.

Comment: Ok so the bounds of the sequence will change depending on your choice of $\varepsilon$ and $m$?

Answer (score 1):

the catch is to think of epsilon as fixed BUT ARBITRARY.

in bartle's book, real analysis, he puts it like so:
it's a game, in which party A makes the statement $|s_{m} −s_{n} | \leq 1$, $\forall{m,n} ≥n_{0}$ .
then, party B comes and challenges that statement by giving party A, a value of epsilon.
party A has to come up with a value for "n" such that, any n greater than that value will oblige to the tested hypothesis.

this game can be played to infinity (thus ANY epsilon).